# MySQLi Insert query executing but not going into database

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have been trying to do an Insert into the my database for the past two days but it's not just working and I don't get any error.
The funniest and probably the most frustrating thing is that this works perfectly on my Laptop Wamp Server but doesn't work when I upload to the internet.

```
<?php

error_reporting;
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "dbuser", "dbpass", "dbname");
if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0)
{
  echo"Failed to connect to MySQL ".$mysqli->connect_error."";
  exit();
}


if($_POST["submit"])
{
$errors=array();
if(isset($_FILES["file"]))
{
$funame=preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]/i',' ',cleanvalues2($_FILES["file"]["name"]));
$dir="../attachment/";
if($funame)
{$frand=rand(0000, 9999);
$funame=$frand.$funame;
$valid_exts=array("jpeg","png","jpg");
$ext=end(explode(".",strtolower($funame)));
$size=$_FILES["file"]["size"];
$type=$_FILES["file"]["type"];
if($size<10)
{
$errors[]="File must be larger than 10Bytes!";
}
if($size>50000000)
{
$errors[]="size too larg!";
}
if(!in_array($ext,$valid_exts))
{
$errors[]="invalid file extension!";}

if(file_exists("$dir.$funame"))
{
$errors[]="File exists please rename this file !";
}
}
}

$name=$_POST["name"];
$email=$_POST["email"];
$clientphonenumber=$_POST["clientphonenumber"];
$parcel=$_POST["parcel"];
$parceldetails=$_POST["parceldetails"];
$phase1=$_POST["phase1"];
$phase1con=$_POST["phase1con"];
$phase2con=$_POST["phase2con"];
$phase2=$_POST["phase2"];
$phase2date=$_POST["phase2date"];
$phase3=$_POST["phase3"];
$phase3con=$_POST["phase3con"];
$phase3date=$_POST["phase3date"];
$save=cleanvalues($_POST["save"]);
//clean
if(empty($parcel)|| strlen($parcel)<2)
{
$errors[]="Package should have a title/name (Will be useful for your tracking)";
}
if(count($errors)==0)
{
$date=time();
$dir=$dir.$funame;
$fin=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $dir);
$query="INSERT INTO track SET `email`=?, `name`=?, `clientphonenumber`=?, `parcel`=?, `parceldetails`=?, `phase1`=?, `phase1con`=?, `phase2`=?, `phase2con`=?, `phase3`=?, `phase3con`=?, `date`=?, `lastdate`=?, `file`=?";
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
if(!$stmt)
{
$msg="An error occured while uploading package, please contact Developer";
}
else
{
$msg='Package was uploaded Successfully';
$stmt->bind_param('ssssssssssssss', $email,$name,$clientphonenumber,$parcel,$parceldetails,$phase1,$phase1con,$phase2,$phase2con,$phase3,$phase3con,$date,$date,$funame);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$last=$mysqli->insert_id;
$iv="SELECT * FROM track WHERE `id`='$last'";
$ivquer=$mysqli->query($iv);
$tt=$ivquer->fetch_array();
$tid=cleanvalues2($tt["id"]);
$tol=time();
$dyear=gmdate('Y', $tol);
$dday=gmdate('d', $tol);
$sentcustom=cleanvalues2($tt["sentcustom"]+1);
$ivquery="UPDATE track SET `packageid`=?, `sentcustom`=? WHERE `id`=?";
$ivstmt=$mysqli->prepare($ivquery);
$ivcode="JIROL-TRACK$dyear$tid$dday";
$ivstmt->bind_param('sss', $ivcode,$sentcustom,$last);
$ivstmt->execute();
$ivstmt->close();
$to="book@domain.com, info@domain.com, domain@yahoo.com";
$subject="Newly Uploaded Package";
$messagel="Hello,
On the website, a package has just been uploaded and its tracking code is $ivcode, You/or your team can forward this to the appropiate quarters and also save/bookmark email for future references
Few Details:
Package: $parcel
Details: $parceldetails
Client Phone Number: $clientphonenumber
For more details on this package or client, Please visit the Website and Click on the appropiate links.

Thanks";
$headers='From: New Uploaded Package Alert - noreply@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$admin=mail($to, $subject, $messagel, $headers);

if(!empty($email))
{
$tou= "$email";
$subjectu="Order has been Fulfilled - Jiro Logistics";
$messageu="Hello $clientname,
We thank you for using our service

Your order [$parcel] has been fulfilled and you can now track and check its status.
Please note that we will likely call you or email you when your package has been fully delivered (or for whatever reason that arises) so we ask that you check your email constantly and therefore remain open for further messages.
Thanks";
$headersu= 'From: Fulfilled Order info@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$participant=mail($tou, $subjectu, $messageu, $headersu);
}
}
if($save=="Come")
{
header("location: $config->url/pages/uploadpackage.php?msg=$msg");
?>
<script>
location.replace("<?php echo"$config->url";?>/pages/uploadpackage.php?msg=<?php echo"$msg";?>")
</script>
<?php
die;
}
elseif($save=="Gopackages")
{header("location: $config->url/pages/showallpackages.php?msg=$msg");
?>
<script>
location.replace("<?php echo"$config->url";?>/pages/showallpackages.php?msg=<?php echo"$msg";?>")
</script>
<?php
die();
}
elseif($save=="Gohome")
{header("location: $config->url");
?>
<script>
location.replace("<?php echo"$config->url";?>")
</script>
<?php
die;
}
elseif($save=="Gocomplete")
{
header("location: $config->url/pages/showallcompleted.php?msg=$msg");
?>
<script>
location.replace("<?php echo"$config->url";?>/pages/showallcompleted.php?msg=<?php echo"$msg";?>")
</script>
<?php
die;
}
}
else
{
foreach($errors as $error)
{
?>
<script>
location.replace('#error')
</script>
<?php
$string.="&bull; $error<br/>";
}
}
}
if($string!==" "){
echo"<a id='error'></a><div class='w3-container w3-red' align='center' style='padding:10px'>$string</div>";
}
echo"";
?>
<form method="post" autocomplete="on" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<?php 
echo"
<div class='w3-container'>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Name <b>(recommended)</b></div>
<div class='w3-twothird'><input type='text' name='name' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' value='$name' placeholder='E.g: Cute Ejiro'></div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Email <b>(recommended)</b></div>
<div class='w3-twothird'><input type='email' name='email' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' value='$email' placeholder='E.g: jiro@domain.com'></div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Client Phone Number <b>(recommended)</b></div>
<div class='w3-twothird'><input type='number' name='clientphonenumber' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' value='$clientphonenumber' placeholder='E.g: 08130444444'></div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Parcel <font color='red'>*</font></div>
<div class='w3-twothird'><input type='text' name='parcel' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' value='$parcel' placeholder='E.g: Nokia 3310'></div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Parcel Details <font color='red'>*</font></div>
<div class='w3-twothird'><textarea rows='3' cols='3' name='parceldetails' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' placeholder='Details about the package...'>$parceldetails</textarea>
</div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-center'><b>Tick the box, if, at the time you are uploading this package, the package has gotten to the phase you are writing on</b></div>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Phase1</div>
<div class='w3-twothird'> <input type='checkbox' name='phase1con' value='1' style='display:inline-block'> <input type='text' name='phase1' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' value='$phase1' placeholder='E.g: Chinese Port' style='display:inline-block;width:250px'></div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Phase2</div>
<div class='w3-twothird'><input type='checkbox' style='display:inline-block' name='phase2con' value='1'>
<input type='text' style='display:inline-block;width:250px' name='phase2' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' value='$phase2' placeholder='E.g: Ken Atlantic Airport'></div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>Phase3</div>
<div class='w3-twothird'><input type='checkbox' style='display:inline-block' name='phase3con' value='1'> <input type='text' name='phase3' class='w3-input w3-border w3-round' style='display:inline-block;width:250px' value='$phase3'></div></div>
<br>
<div class='w3-row'><div class='w3-third'>
Attach Photo of product</div><div class='w3-twothird'><font color='black'><strong>Allowed Extension: .png, .jpg, .jpeg</strong></font><br>
<input type='file' name='file' size='9'></div></div><br>";

echo"<center>
   <table border='0' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0' style='border:none'>
    <tr style='background:none;border:none'>
        <td style='border:none' valign='middle' nowrap='nowrap'>
<i class='fa fa-check-square'></i> <b>Save and then</b>
        </td>
        <td style='border:none' valign='middle' nowrap='nowrap'>
<select name='save' style='width:220px'>
<option value='Gohome'>Go to Homepage</option>
<option value='Gopackages'>Go to page that shows all packages</option>
<option value='Come' selected='selected'>Come back to this page</option>
<option value='Gocomplete'>Go to page that shows all completed packages</option>
</select>        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</center>";
echo"<input type='submit' name='submit' class='w3-btn w3-osblue' value='Upload'></div></form>
<br/>";
?>
```

The "Track" table is longer than this but I don't think that could be the cause. And the entire DB is MyISAM

I have tried several things:
  - Added $mysqli->commit; and still doesn't work
  - Ran the Query in my PHPMYADMIN (and it worked - got into the database)
  - Changed the code to Procedural and still doesn't work.

I have seen similar questions here on Stack overflow and I have tried everything possible.
Please check and see if there are any errors whatsoever or wrong code.
PS: This code works perfectly on my laptop wamp server and get inserted into my database (without internet) but doesn't work when I upload to my website on the internet.

What did I do wrong and what do I correct?

Comment: Probably you don't have permissions. For executing PHP, for accessing the database, for inserting in the database ... It's hard to tell if you don't show any trace. The error is not being shown to you but probably is being traced in your server.

Comment: Did you mean it is not working on your hosted server ?

Comment: I think this should be due to any configuration that might be missed while moving to the server. You can enable the mysql logging in phpmyadmin and see any errors are logged.

Comment: @RubioRic I have permission to insert into the database. This is the only table that is having this error on my database. What permission will I need for executing, please.

Comment: Yes @Rohit.007 it's not working on my hosted server. Any reason or solution?

Comment: If you have executed PHP code that affects other tables maybe that specific table got not all permissions granted for your db user

Comment: Do you have different versions of PHP and Mysql? have tried by enabling PHP error mode? It may be possible that the application is throwing the error and due to the PHP: error_reporting you are not able to see it OR check whether MySql strict mode is causing any problem

Comment: Okay, Thanks @RubioRic how do I grant that specific table the required permission?

Comment: @Rohit.007 Thanks. That's why this is frustrating, if the problem is with the entire database, other tables will have this problem too but they are not. How do I check if the Mysql strict mode is causing any problem?

Comment: I'm a bit rusty in PHPadmin but each table should have a section showing you its granted permissions. Find it and compare one of the "good" tables with the problematic one. In this same section, you should be allowed to grant new permissions to an specific user